# SonarQube-6.7.1 How to limit the projects seen by users

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube-6.7.1.
We have several teams (6) who share the one production instance.
They are asking me to find a way to limit the scope of the users.
They want to see only their own projects.
What is the best way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the [projects' Browse permissions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-ProjectPermissions) to only the relevant people.

Start by removing the ability of "Anyone" (a special group in SonarQube that includes anonymous) to see the projects, then grant Browse as needed.

This will be easiest in the long term if you first create [groups](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-Group), and grant permissions to the groups rather than to the individual users.

Comment: Thanks.   We can always count on you for good SonaerQube advice.

Comment: @buildmaster if this answered your question or solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I followed your advice but I got stuck, associating jobs and groups was not straitforward.   I had to look for more information because the documentation was not sufficient to get me there.